# How to render the textfield from custom advanced theme setting?

Tags: 7, forms

I'm working on a custom theme with message field(textfield) in custom advanced theme setting.

In "theme-settings.php", I added a "***textfield***" for "***message***" field

```
<?php
function MYTHEME_form_system_theme_settings_alter(&$form, $form_state) {
    $form['message_value'] = array(
        '#type'     => 'textfield',
        '#size' => 12,
        '#maxlength' => 100,
        '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('message_value'),
        '#description' => t('Some text here'),
    );
}
?>
```

In "***template.php***", I added "***theme_get_setting***"

```
<?php
  function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
    $message = theme_get_setting('message_value');
  }
```

And in my "***page.tpl.php***", I render the "***message***" if it is not empty

```
<?php if(!empty($message)) echo $message; ?>
```

The problem is, it does not render anything and has no error.

It works if I put the theme_get_setting in page.tpl.php

```
<?php $message = theme_get_setting('message_value'); ?>
```

How to make it work if I want to put that in ***"template.php"***?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your template.php preprocess function, you need to pass the message back as a key/value in the variables array. (I set the variable key as "custom_msg" as "message" may be too generic and be accidentally confused with any system message variables"

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
    $message = theme_get_setting('message_value');
    $vars['custom_msg'] = $message;
}
```

Then, in your page.tpl.php, the variable would be accessible as $custom_msg (or whatever custom key you set in the preprocess function) and can be included in your page template as:

```
<?php if(!empty($custom_msg)) echo $custom_msg; ?>
```

More information about this can be found on this Drupal.org page: [*Setting up variables for use in a template (preprocess and process functions)*](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/overriding-themable-output/setting-up-variables-for-use-in-a-template-preprocess-and)

Answer (score 2):

Your code in template.php needs modification

instead of $message, you need to mention `$vars['message']`. If you need to send a variable from template.php file to a tpl file, then the variable has to be mentioned in `$vars['variable_name']` or   `$variables['variable_name']`, depending upon the argument set in the preprocess method.

So here goes the modification to your code:

`function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {

    $vars['message'] = theme_get_setting('message_value');

  }`

And then in you tpl file, you will be able to render the 'message' variable.

```
if(!empty($message)) echo $message;
```